# Can't open a project

Tags: c++, cuda

I downloaded the source code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42192/Fast-Image-Blurring-with-CUDA) to learn cuda but its not opening correctly, it showing me this window.

[image]

Edit: There is no such path in my computer (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\cuda.targets)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right-click each project and click `Reload Project`.

Comment: @xoemab Try `Project-> Build Customizations` and then select the correct CUDA `.targets` and `.props`.